# Null reference exception creates when datagrid rows are not visible within datagrid in C# WPF

Tags: c#, sql, database, wpf, datagrid

In C# WPF, Null reference exception creates when datagrid rows are not visible within grid (It occurs when there are rows which can be seen by scrolling down the datagrid) how can I avoid that? I am new to WPF.

My Code:

```
foreach (DataRowView dr in datagrid.ItemsSource)
        {
            DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["date2"]);
            DateTime currentdate = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime upcomingdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(+5);

            if (date2 < currentdate)
            {
                var Srow = datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dr) as DataGridRow;
                Srow.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }
            else if (date2 < upcomingdate)
            {
                var Srow1 = datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dr) as DataGridRow;
                Srow1.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Due to [virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), ContainerFromItem may return null. You should not set the Foreground in code behind. Instead, bind it to a property of the item class. You may use a Binding Converter to convert an arbitrary input value to a Brush.

Comment: @Clemens Dear Clemens, Thank you for the reply! can you tell more about how to do that? sorry for asking. But I am very new to WPF.

Comment: There is really plenty of information available. May start reading here: [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0).

Comment: Ok. I will check. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Otherwise just try to set `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` on the DataGrid.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Actually it worked when I set EnableRowVirtualization="False" on the DataGrid.

Comment: Sure, but you are switching off virtualization, which may have an impact on performance with large amounts of data. And accessing DataGridRows like this isn't recommended. Better search for a solution where you bind the Foreground property.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I will check about that.